# Getting value in getItem() different than what expected

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-adapter

I am currently working with `FragmentStatePager` and i have not much idea about what's going on in the functions related. Specifically, I am confused about `getItem()` method.

I have such an inner `class`:

```
   public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ...
    }
   .....
   ......
  }
```

Outside this class, i have such a function:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction 
fragmentTransaction){


 mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());


}
```

Now I am having a problem, and getting no clue. When debugging,  i click on the section 1(position 1) of this adapter in the app, i get `tab.getPosition() == 1` in `onTabSelected()` function, nicely. But then it jumps to `getItem(int position)` func , here I get the `position == 2`. It is just strange, and between these two functions, I get no other code that would change the `position` from `1` to `2`. Do any of you have any clue? So please share it and help me.

Edit: When the adapter firstly loads, it sets firstly 2 sections(position 0 and 1) among 3. I think, then when I click on section 2(position 1) then it loads section 2 (position 3). If it happens, how to overcome this?

I need to load section 2 when I'll click on section 2. How to do this?

Comment: The `ViewPager` is loading one page ahead, so the next page is ready to be swiped on-screen.

Comment: But i need to load then the very page.

Comment: Did you try setting OffScreenPageLimit to 0?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying like this `mViewpager.setOffScreenPageLimit(0)`. But debugging, I can see the `mOffscreenPageLimit` to be `1` still. Btw, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's Default behavior of viewpager, it loads one page of ahead and back of current page by default.
You can get using OffScreenPageLimit from ViewPager.

Check officail doc from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))
It's default value is 1, which means 1 page of both sides of current page will be loaded.
You can change that using **setOffscreenPageLimit** method of ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `Man` It's Default behavior of viewpager.

> I need to load section 2 when i'll click on section 2. How to do this?

You can use `setUserVisibleHint`. load your fragment data(API call, etc) when its visible to the user

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
        //do your api call etc
    }
}
```